# How to code query from SQL in Java for object oriented metamodel

Tags: java, sql, object-oriented-database

I'm trying to learn how to create an object oriented model database using a tool called: Eyedb (on linux). I've made some classes and records generators for this database but I don't know how to code queries for it using Java.

The structure of the database looks like this:

```
    class Lecturer {

        attribute string<32> name;
        attribute strin<32> surname;
        relationship set <Lecture*> lectures inverse Lecture::Lecturer;
};

class Item{
        attribute string<32> name;
        attribute string<512> description;
};

class Topic extends Item {
        relationship set<Lecture*> tlecture inverse Lecture::Topic;
};


class Lecture {
        relationship Lecturer *llecturer inverse Lecturer::lectures;
        relationship Topic *ltopic inverse Topic::tlecture;
        relationship set <Content*> lcontent inverse Content::Lecture;
        relationship set <Equipment*> lequipment inverse Content::Lecture;
        relationship Room_timeslot* lroom_timeslot inverse Room_timeslot::rlecture;                                                     
};

class Content extends Item {

        attribute int level;
        relationship set <Content*> subcontent inverse Content::supcontent; 
        relationship set <Content*> supcontent inverse  Content::subcontent;    
        relationship set <Teachingmaterial*> cteachingmaterial inverse Teachingmaterial::Content;
};

class Teachingmaterial extends Item {

        attribute string link;
        relationship set <Content*> tcontent inverse Content::Teachingmaterial;
};

class Equipment extends Item {
        attribute int quantity;
        attribute string symbol;
        relationship set<Lecture*> electure inverse Lecture::Equipment;
        relationship Room *eroom inverse Room::requipment;

};

class Room {
        relationship set <Equipment*> requipment inverse Equipment::Room
        attribute string name;
        attribute int number;
        attribute string symbol;
        attribute string building;
        attribute int floor;
        attribute string wing;
        relationship set <Room_timeslot*> rroom_timeslot inverse Room_timeslot::Room;
};

class Room_timeslot {
        relationship Room *room inverse room::rroom_timeslot;
        relationship Lecture* rlecture inverse Lecture::Room_timeslot;
        relationship set <Timeslot*> rtimeslot inverse Timeslot::lroom_timeslot;
};

class Timeslot {
        attribute string name;
        attribute int number;
        attribute time timemargin_start;
        attribute time timemargin_end;
        relationship set <Room_timeslot*> troom_timeslot inverse Room_timeslot::rtimeslot;
};
```

I want to make queries that look like this:

```
SELECT lr.name as lecturer, t.name as topic FROM topic t        
JOIN lecture l ON t.id_topic = l.id_topic
JOIN lecturer lr ON lr.id_lecturer = l.id_lecturer
ORDER BY lr.name

select t.name as topic from topic t 
join lecture l on t.id_topic = l.id_topic 
join lecturer lr on lr.id_lecturer = l.id_lecturer
where lr.name = "name1"

SELECT tm.name as teaching_material, e.name as equipment, lr.name as lecturer FROM teachingmaterial tm
JOIN teaching_content tc ON tc.id_teachingmaterial = tm.id_teachingmaterial
JOIN content c ON c.id_content = tc.id_content
JOIN content_lecture cl ON cl.id_content = c.id_content
JOIN lecture l ON l.id_lecture = cl.id_lecture
JOIN lecture_equipment le ON le.id_lecture = l.id_lecture
JOIN equipment e ON e.id_equipment = le.id_equipment
JOIN lecturer lr ON lr.id_lecturer = l.id_lecturer
```

Comment: This is not learning school or teaching center. Here you can get help with the technical problems.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses JDBC to communicate with a relational database.  If your database has a JDBC driver you're all set.  If not, you're out of luck.  Both SQL Server and MySQL have JDBC drivers, so they should not be a problem.  You'll need those and the [JDBC tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/).

Looks like [EyeDB](http://www.eyedb.org/) is an object database that I've never heard of.  It claims to be usable by C++ and Java.

I'd expect at least one "hello world" connection example.  I'm suspicious of any software that doesn't even get the HTML on its web page right.

There's [Java documentation](http://www.eyedb.org/wp-content/uploads/eyedb-doc-current/manual/html/JavaBinding/node1.html) available.  Looks awful.  Is this a requirement?  There are better databases, both relational (MySQL, SQLLite, or PostgreSQL), object (e.g. [JODB](http://www.java-objects-database.com/)), or graph (NEO4J).  Must you use this one?

The EyeDB documentation makes the steps clear.  They are spelled out for you in the [sample problem](http://www.eyedb.org/wp-content/uploads/eyedb-doc-current/manual/html/JavaBinding/node3.html#SECTION00212000000000000000):

1. Define the schema using the EyeDB Object Definition Language (ODL)
2. Generate the Java classes from the schema using the EyeDB eyedbodl tool, which comes with your download.
3. Write a client program using the generated classes that interact with the database.

It's all there.  Give it a try.

Comment: Sadly it's requirement. I have to compare relational databases (2 of them one in sql server and one in phpmyadmin) and one object oriented. I'd propalby use anothere one (not eyedb) but someone above me decided that this one is the closest to object oriented "doctrine" (sorry for my english). I didn't find anything related to queries in documentation so i asked here. I saw how insert looks like, drop and modify (update), but i don't know how to adjust my querries from sql to java.

Comment: Your object database queries will NOT be SQL, because that's the language of relational databases.  Object databases are not relational.  You can use JDBC to communicate with SQL Server easily in Java.  Have a look at the JDBC tutorial.  You're on your own with EyeDB.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/

Comment: I heard that i should use OQL in those querries but i don't know the gramma of if. Should I search for it or use the tool that You described? Im sorry for my lack of knowledge but im new in this section of IT and i got really low amout of time to do my task.

Comment: There is no object oriented query grammar.  They are all non-standard.  That's one reason why they are niche products, not in general use.  You should be devouring that documentation link on the EyeDB and seeing how to use it.  Your lack of time isn't my problem; I can't give you back the time you need to learn it.  Give it a try and do your best.

Comment: For my classes the insert would look sorta like this i suppose:

'Lecturer lecturer = new Lecturer(new);  //name of database?
lecturer.setname("name"+Integer.toString(i));
lecturer.setsurname("surname_"+Integer.toString(i));
lecturer.store();'

But how to do the same queries as i wrote down higher with this?

Comment: Please.  I don't understand your question.  Calm down and go through that tutorial.    Take a breath, do your best, and accept what comes next.  Do you have the relational part of the assignment done?  Do what you can.

Comment: I have made those 2 relational databases. I filled them with data and checked those querriest that i wrote above. The object oriented database is the only problem. Sorry for my approach to this topic but I thought that someone had worked with this type of database and would help to set an exaple that i could follow and try to adjust my querries by it. Thank you for your help with this link and your advices. If you have some more I'll gladly take them ;]

Comment: So you've completed two parts of a three part assignment?  That's good.  Going through that sample problem, getting it to work, and adapting it to your problem should not be more than an afternoon's work.  You can do it.  Just keep emotion out of it and keep making progress.  The point is to learn and understand.

Comment: One more thing. If i have jdbc i can communicate with database using sql. And if i don't have i'll have to use oql?

Comment: Yes, SQL is for relational databases.  JDBC is about SQL and relational databases.  The link I sent you tells you how to query your object database.  There is no standard way; there is no grammar.  That's one reason why object databases have only caught on in niche markets (e.g. graphics, computer aided design, etc.)

Comment: So it's a matter of implementing it into structure and using it? But how to check if it's compatybile with database? Im afraid a bit to screw things up.

Comment: You're a student. Stop being afraid. Give it a try. Take your lumps. You'll learn before or after the assignment. The point is to learn. You can't be a developer (or anything else) if you're so afraid to fail.